# Pull data from excel into Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pysimplegui, python-o365

I am working on a menu app and I need it to be dynamic.

1. I am having trouble figuring out how I would be able to pull data from an excel sheet into my 'menu_dictionary' value.
2. I want to be able to change the prices without having to manually change the code
3. I also want to be able to make the excel file accessible from a OneDrive account so it can be updated to a different computer from another.
4. create a new .exe file. is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

menu_dictionary = {
    "Cheese": 0.50,
    "Sandwhich": 1.75,
    "Pickles": 0.25,
    "Hot Dog": 1.25,
    "Burger": 3.5,
    "Onions": 0.75,
    "Bacon": 1.25,
    "Eggs": 1.00,
    "Fries": 1.25,
    "Chips": 1.25,
    "Salad": 1.25,
    "Potatoes": 1.25,
    "Ranch": 1.25,
    "Ketchup": 1.25,
    "BBQ": 1.25,
    "Drinks": 1.25,
}

Total = 0
items = []
Name = ''
sg.theme("DarkTeal9")
x = ''
EXCEL_FILE = 'MenuTest1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Welcom to the MAF Menu ")],
    [sg.Text('Name'), sg.InputText(key='Name'), sg.Text('Site'),
     sg.Combo(["A01", "B01", "C01", "D01", "E01", "F01", "G01", "H01", "I01", "J01", "K01", "L01", "M01", "N01", "O01"],
              key='Site')],
    [sg.Text("Total:"), sg.InputText('$' + str(Total), key='Cost', size=5)],
    [sg.Text('Meal Time'),
     sg.Checkbox('Breakfast', key='Breakfast'),
     sg.Checkbox('Lunch', key='Lunch'),
     sg.Checkbox('Dinner', key='Dinner')],
    [sg.Text("Entrees"), sg.Button("Burger"), sg.Button("Sandwhich"), sg.Button("Hot Dog"), sg.Button("Eggs")],
    [sg.Text("Toppings"), sg.Button("Onions"), sg.Button("Pickles"), sg.Button("Cheese")],
    [sg.Text("Sides"), sg.Button("Fries"), sg.Button("Chips"), sg.Button("Salad"), sg.Button("Potatoes")],
    [sg.Text('Condiments'), sg.Button("Ranch"), sg.Button("Ketchup"), sg.Button("BBQ")],
    [sg.Text("Beverages"), sg.Button("Drinks")],
    [sg.Button("Review"), sg.Multiline(x, key='New', size=(20, 5))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button("Clear"), sg.Exit()],
]

window = sg.Window('Sample', layout)


def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        items = []
        Name = ''
        Total = 0

        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'Clear':
        Total = 0
        clear_input()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break

    if event == 'Submit':

        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data Stored')
        clear_input()
        Total = 0
        window['Cost'].update(Total)


    if event == "Review":
        order = ", ".join(items)
        order = "{} Order: {}".format(Name, order)
        x = Name + order + " for $" + str(Total)
        window['New'].update(x)

    if event in menu_dictionary:
        Total = Total + menu_dictionary[event]
        if event not in items:
            items.append(event)

        window['Cost'].update('$' + str(Total))

window.close()
```

Comment: Welcome. You have about 3 questions. You can give `pyinstaller` library a read regarding packaging your application. You may want to read more on `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with **OneDrive**.
In Onedrive, simply *share* your Excel file and copy the URL (`Copy Link`). If you need to write back to the Excel file, you must share it with edit right. Actually, this is #insecure!
[proceed with caution! | insecure access ahead]

- Get OneDrive link
- Parse OneDrive link to get 'direct access'
- Read Excel file into pandas with `pd.read_excel(onedrivedirectlink)
  [See Santhanavanich article.](https://towardsdatascience.com/onedrive-as-data-storage-for-python-project-2ff8d2d3a0aa)
  Read more on [pandas-read-excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

What to do in `Python`: for more prudent access to your Excel file securely.
Use the [O365 Python](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) or [office365 API](https://github.com/O365/python-o365#excel) libraries

1. import libraries
2. authenticate
3. access Excel file
4. interact with file

The **second part**: ***pull data from an excel sheet into my 'menu_dictionary' value***
The `menu_dictionary` you define must map to your `df`

***dynamically change pricing***:
All that is left is for you to make changes in your OneDrive Excel file as you desire.

[pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) gives you flexibility in writing to Excel file.
[Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), on the other hand, enable you to engage Excel file robustly. You can use other libraries.

Lastly, ***create .exe***:
You may want to leverage Python library, [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html) for your `.exe`